# ASP.NET 3.5 C# HTTP Post Error Using JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I've tried many different stackoverflow questions asked to find an answer and I never found one that fixes this issue. I was able to make HTTP Requests using ASP.NET 4.5 Framework but I need to do this for version 3.5 instead, the displays the error below:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

The code is shown below. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.baseUrl + "/api_users");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        //httpWebRequestProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            if (this.debug == true)
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                this.emailBody += "User POST Request Successful: " + result + "<br /><br />";
            }
        }
```

Comment: ProTip: The [`WebClient` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is easier to use than plain `HttpWebRequest` if you don't need the streaming behavior and all, and it's available from .NET 1.1.

Comment: Set urlencoding property beore sending the request, httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";. Is this issue only specific to POST? or you get the same error in "Get"?

Comment: Same error occurs when I added in the content type. This issue happens to all 4 major HTTP requests: GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE.

Comment: If your code works under 4.5 and not 3.5, then the easiest way to debug this is to use a tool, such as Fiddler, and run it under .NET 4.5 and then under .NET 3.5 and see what the difference is between the two requests.

Comment: I just tested WebClient class it it didn't work as well. The error appears to be the same so it has to be something with KeepAlive or ServicePoint.Expect100Continue inside the HttpWebRequest object. I set them to false and they still donot work though.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, how I write string to requeststream is like below:

```
        if (httpMethod == HttpMethods.POST)
        {
            var postData = "some string";
            var postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

            using (var postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                postStream.Flush();
                postStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to set ContentLength to the exact number of bytes.